# NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail is not getting reflected

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uilabel

Hi I have a UILabel which is added as a subview of a table view cell.I want a long text in one line with dots at the end.But if I put the numberOfLines as 1 , then the label width can not be set. The label tries to display the entire text in 1 line and goes out of the cell. If i make the numberOfLines to 0, and lineBreakMode to NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail then the text goes into two lines.I am adding the piece of code below,.

```
self.titleTextField = [[UILabel alloc] init];
 [self.titleTextField setFrame:CGRectMake(45, 33, self.arrowMark.frame.origin.x-self.titleTextField.frame.origin.x, self.titleTextField.frame.size.height)];
        //newly added_jacket

        self.titleTextField.numberOfLines =0;
        self.titleTextField.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;
        self.titleTextField.textColor =[UIColor colorWithRed:30.0f/255.0f green:164.0f/255.0f blue:220.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0];
        [self.titleTextField setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
        [self.titleTextField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];


        [self.cellBGImage addSubview:self.titleTextField];
        [self.titleTextField sizeToFit];
```

Pease help me with this.

Comment: you can take one view inside a tableview cell and put that uilable in that so it can got out of view

Comment: @hardik vyas :I did like that only. self.cellBGImage is a UIImageView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just remove **[self.titleTextField sizeToFit];** this line and NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail will work pefactly.